# ICU timezone and dst

Tags: c++, timezone, icu

1. How do I convert local time to a specific time zone including dst using ICU in c++?
   I saw an example but it doesn't take into account dts.
2. is it enough to update the zoneinfo file on the Linux server without updating the ICU library so that ICU will use the updates time zones?

Comment: You mean DST (not dts).  Can you please elaborate more about the example you mention and what you *tried*?

Comment: Also, just guessing from the wording, but you may find CCTZ more useful than ICU.

Comment: In what way CCTZ is better than ICU? How can I update the timezones without updating all the ICU library?

Comment: It's only focused on time zone conversions, rather than localization of strings. And it relies on the system's time zone data, rather than bundling it - which I believe is what you were looking for.